# Classic vs Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, classic-experience

We have been thinking to switch from classic experience to the modern one.

One of the reasons is the bulk edit.

Can anyone list the pros and cons of these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Quick Edit/Bulk Edit** in both Classic as well as Modern experience in SharePoint Online.

However, you can find the differences between Classic and Modern Experience in below articles:

1. [SharePoint classic and modern experiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f).
2. [What is Modern SharePoint? Modern SharePoint vs Classic SharePoint in SharePoint Online](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/what-is-modern-sharepoint-and-modern-sharepoint-vs-classic-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-online/).
3. [What's the difference between classic and modern SharePoint team sites?](https://sharegate.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-classic-and-modern-sharepoint-team-sites).

At the end, the choice of classic/modern is depend on the features you are going to use from those experiences.

Comment: thank you, However you can't change the content type of multiple items in classic experience

Comment: Are you able to change the content type of multiple items in Modern experience?

Comment: yes , there i this new feature that allows you to do that

Comment: I am not able to change the content type of multiple list items from **Quick Edit** in Modern experience.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wReS3oBIOE

Comment: Cool. I was checking it using **Quick Edit** option from top ribbon. While we can use **Bulk Edit Properties option** from **Details pane** (Next to filter pane).

Comment: Hi Ed1995, If this answer helps you then please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will not be shown in Unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the links from which you can find the pros and cons.

[pros and cons](https://www.withum.com/resources/the-pros-and-cons-of-sharepoint-modern-sites/)

[Cons of Modern UI](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Classic-vs-Modern/td-p/283464)

[Classic vs. Modern UI](https://www.kieferconsulting.com/2019/03/11/sharepoint-classic-vs-sharepoint-modern-a-kiefer-assessment-part-1/)